# Is there a way to get notified when a user adds a new calendar entry

Tags: android, calendar

Can i get informed in my android application when a user adds a new entry in his calendar application (i.e. via listeners, ...) or is checking the calendar every now and then via the content provider of the calendar app the only solution to find out if the user has added new entries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can i get informed in my android
>   application when a user adds a new
>   entry in his calendar application
>   (i.e. via listeners, ...)

There is no calendar application in the Android SDK. There is a calendar application in the open source project, but it may or may not exist on any given device, since device manufacturers are welcome to replace it. It is also possible that the user will download an alternative calendar application that replaces the built-in one.

> is checking the calendar every now and
>   then via the content provider of the
>   calendar app the only solution to find
>   out if the user has added new entries
>   ?

There is no calendar content provider in the Android SDK. There is a content provider used by the calendar application in the open source project, but see above for the issues with relying upon that application. Also, the core Android team wishes that you would not rely upon [undocumented content providers](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html).

If you wish to work with Google Calendar, please use the [appropriate GData APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/), until and unless more calendar functionality is added to the SDK.