# Google Calendar doubt?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am new to android. I need to add events to Google calendar from my application. How to integrate with google calendar? What are the jar files are needed? Is it needed to enable any gmail setting? I need some help .Can anyone help me to solve this??

Comment: The field in the upper-right of most StackOverflow pages is a search field. You can search for posts with certain tags by enclosing them in square brackets. A search for `[android] calendar` turns up over 60 posts. Some of these are relevant to you, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974275/is-there-a-way-to-get-notified-when-a-user-adds-a-new-calendar-entry and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976927/android-how-to-interface-with-google-calendar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023557/when-will-android-have-a-public-calendar-api

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

Here google does a good guide to integrate it